# RxAndroid and multithreading

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I am using RxAndroid to do some stuff in the background. This is my code:

```
Observable<MyClass[]> observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<MyClass[]>() {

        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super MyClass[]> subscriber) {
                System.out.println(Looper.myLooper() + " - " + Looper.getMainLooper());
                try {
                    MyObject myObject = ...
                    //do the background work
                    subscriber.onNext(myObject);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                  .subscribe(new Action1<MyClass[]>() {
                      @Override
                      public void call(MyClass[] myObjects) {
                          //do work on the ui Thread
                      }
                  }
        );
```

This is my first time using `RxAndroid / RxJava / Looper.myLooper() / Looper.getMainLooper()`

From what I am told, `Looper.myLooper()` gives you the name ID of the thread the current code is running on and `Looper.getMainLooper()` gives you the ID of the main Thread. When I run the app, in the `SysOut`, it prints out the same id for both of them.

Am I doing something wrong or am I misunderstanding the 2 Looper functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended that you don't use `Observable.create` unless you *really* know what you are doing with Observables.  There are a lot of things that you can potentially get wrong.

The reason your code inside your create is running on the main thread here is that it is being called when the Observable is being created **not** when you are subscribing to it.

For what you are trying to achieve I would use `Observable.defer`  From the [docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html):

> The Defer operator waits until an observer subscribes to it, and then it generates an Observable, typically with an Observable factory function.

The code would look something like:

```
Observable<MyObject> observable = Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<MyObject>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<MyObject> call() {

        System.out.println(Looper.myLooper() + " - " + Looper.getMainLooper());

        try {
            MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
            return Observable.just(myObject);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return Observable.error(e);
        }

    }
});

Subscription s = observable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
                new Action1<MyObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(MyObject myObject) {

                    }
                },
                new Action1<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        );
```

Now in your logcat you will get:

```
I/System.out: null - Looper (main, tid 1) {5282c4e0}
```

The reason the `Looper.myLooper()` function returns null is that when you create a new thread unless you call `Looper.prepare()` the thread will not have a looper.  You generally don't need a looper on a thread unless you want to post a `Runnable` to it anyhow.

Comment: Hey. Sorry. Been away for a while. I'll try this out tonight and get back to you :)